# To show that $S(\mathbb R)$ is contained in $C_0(\mathbb R)$

Tags: fourier-analysis

I have to show if function is in schwarz space $S(\mathbb R)$, then it is also in $C_0(\mathbb R )$(continuous functions dying at infiinity).

$f\in S(\mathbb R) $means $f$ is infinitely many times differentiable and for any $n,m \in \mathbb N_0$, sup$\mid x^mf^n(x) \mid$ is finite over $\mathbb R$. Now clearly $f$ from schwarz space is continuous but how can I show that $\forall \epsilon>0$, there exist compact set $K_\epsilon$, such that outside $K_\epsilon$, $\mid f(x) \mid< \epsilon$, which is condition for  $C_0(\mathbb R )$. I am not coming with any idea about the construction of $K_\epsilon$. Any hint.

Comment: Taking $n=0$ and $m=1$ you have the condition that $$\sup_{x \in \Bbb R}|xf(x)| < \infty$$ this is equivalent to $f(x)= O(1/x)$. In other words, $f(x)$ vanishes at infinity.

Comment: Thanks @Crostul

Comment: Isn’t $C_0(\mathbb R)$ means continuous function with a finite support?

Comment: In my notes, these are continuous functions dying at infinity